# I want to get the userid from firebase when i enter the email in ionic

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, ionic3, firebase-authentication

I'm setting up a search method. So i want to get the ***userid*** from the authentication when i enter the ***email*** of specific account.

**Note** : I have registered users using createUserWithEmailAndPassword method..

Comment: You should show 1. what you have so far 2. what you want to achive you can also check the angularFire2 https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for a search function you will need a list of all users. And you can get the uid of the user by its email.

You can do this by using the firebase admin sdk.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

It has a listusers function:

```
admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then(function(listUsersResult) {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
        console.log('user', userRecord.toJSON());
      });
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
        // List next batch of users.
        listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Error listing users:', error);
    });
```

And also have getuserbyemail function:

```
admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully fetched user data:', userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
   console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
  });
```